# partition text with no fixed width

Tags: csv, text, awk

I have some text like this

```
blue chile               green   morning dawn
red  turkey              pink    morning dawn
white south africa       red     evening midst & more
```

I would like to split it like this (notice the pipe delimiter)

```
blue child | green morning dawn
red turkey | pink morning dawn
white south africa | red evening midst & more
```

There aren't fixed width so I am having trouble partitioning the text

Comment: They look fixed width to me. What makes you say they aren't?

Comment: Yes, they are fixed width! Just realized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This MIGHT be what you're looking for:

```
$ sed -E 's/ {3,}/ | /; s/  */ /g' file
blue chile | green morning dawn
red turkey | pink morning dawn
white south africa | red evening midst & more
```

The above assumes your 2 "fields" are separated by 3 or more blank chars as in your posted sample input. It will work in GNU or OSX sed for `-E` to enable EREs.

Otherwise, if the fields really ARE fixed width as it appears in your posted input then for improved robustness consider using GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='25 8 999' -v OFS=' | ' '{print $1, $2, $3}' file
blue chile                | green    | morning dawn
red  turkey               | pink     | morning dawn
white south africa        | red      | evening midst & more

$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='25 8 999' -v OFS=' | ' '{print $1, $2 $3}' file
blue chile                | green   morning dawn
red  turkey               | pink    morning dawn
white south africa        | red     evening midst & more

$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='25 8 999' -v OFS=' | ' '{$0 = $1 OFS $2 $3; gsub(/ +/," ")} 1' file
blue chile | green morning dawn
red turkey | pink morning dawn
white south africa | red evening midst & more
```

Comment: didn't know about FIELDWIDTHs. So, is it possible to partition with column number, 25, 55, and 67?

Comment: Yes, whatever you like... see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size. With other awks you'd use a `while() substr()` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the substr and fieldwidths tip

Answer (score 1):

if you want to normalize spaces in addition to the pipe delimiter

```
$ sed -r 's/(.{25})/\1 | /' file | tr -s ' '

blue chile | green morning dawn
red turkey | pink morning dawn
white south africa | red evening midst & more
```

this matches your output but note that the extra space in `red  turkey` is removed as well.  If you want to preserve it, it will require extra steps.